# Inject validator in ASP.NET core filter

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the following ASP.NET Core controller action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Model model) { 

   IValidator<Model> validator = new Validator<Model>();

   if (!validator.IsValid)
      return await validation.ToErrorResponse();

   // Remaining code

}
```

I configured ASP.NET core to inject IValidator on Startup.

I would like to make the validation automatic using a filter:

```
public class ValidateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {

public overrideTask OnActionExecutionAsync(
    ActionExecutingContext context, 
    ActionExecutionDelegate next) {

    }
}
```

Inside the filter I need to request the correct Validator according to the Model being submitted and returning the errors.

How can I get the validator and the model being submitted inside the filter?

Comment: You wrote: "I configured ASP.NET core to inject IValidator<Model> on Startup." Could you please show the code that you used to do that.